# Diophantine Inequalities

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, diophantine-equations

I am trying to research ways to come up with better ways of factoring, which is why in any answer, I would not like factoring as that would defeat the whole point. As I was working, I came across this equation for one of my test values:$$y=x^2+12x+3$$To continue with my methods, I am asking what positive integer values of $k$ make this inequality true: $$N^2<k(x^2+12x+3)<(N+2)^2$$ where $N$ is a polynomial.

Comment: Thank you! Is something wrong with my question?

Comment: It has the essence of a good question. You will get a much better response if you can provide more context for the problem and detail your solution efforts so far.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok, are my current edits good?

Comment: Good. Can you specify the domain of $x$. Is it, for example, $\mathbb{R}^{+}$?

Comment: I just edited it, saying that it is.

Comment: I just wished that this would get more attention.

Answer (score 1):

Having given a lot of attention to that quickly stated problem, I and perhaps others, wonder if the following is the intended question.

Given a polynomial $p(x)$ with positive integer coefficients,
for what positive integers $k$, is, for all real $x$,
$p(x)^2 < k(x^2 + 12x + 3) < (p(x) + 2)^2$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: The number of k's depends upon p(x) and can be none.

Comment: So there is no general solution?